Evidence for Dark Energy that *distinguishes* between a CDM model with a non-homogeneous universe from the standard $\Lambda$CDM Model
Has any evidence been found that distinguishes between a CDM model with a non-homogeneous universe and the standard $\Lambda$CDM Model ?

What exactly is your question ? Are you asking whether such evidence has been found ? Or are you asking what evidence could, if it were found, distinguish between these models ?

@Sten I am asking what evidence has been found that distinguishes a universe with cold dark matter where we live in a giant void, vs the lambda CDM model.
In other words we assume cold dark matter to explain lensing, acoustic oscillations, velocity curves, but we assume the expansion happened due to non-homogeneity.
I know dark matter has lots of evidence, as not just modified gravity, but what about the current approach to dark energy.
Have ever measured an inflation field?
